# Solving $|1-\frac{3}{x}|\le 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I did:

$$|1-\frac{3}{x}|\le 2 \iff \\
1-\frac{3}{x}\le2 \lor -1+\frac{3}{x}\le2\iff \\
-\frac{3}{x}\le2-1 \lor \frac{3}{x}\le 2+1 \iff \\
\frac{3}{x}\ge-1 \lor \frac{3}{x}\le3 \iff \\
x \ge -3 \lor x\le1$$

Apparently this is correct only the symbols are the other way around on the last step. Why? Was it because when you raise numbers to -1 you have to invert the signs? Is this true for all negative powers?

Comment: You are using $\lor$, which is used for `or`. The first equivalence is actually an `and`.

Comment: The other problem is at the very end. The inequality $\frac{3}{x}\geq-1$, would give, for $x>0$, $3\geq-x$ by multiplying by $x$ and then $x\geq -3$ as you got. But there is another case, if $x<0$ then it becomes $3\leq-x$ and from there $-3\geq x$. In other words, you are missing cases (and you added cases due to using `or` instead of `and`).

Comment: Use $\frac{3}{x}\geq -1\iff \frac{3}{x}+1\geq 0\iff \frac{x+3}{x}\geq 0$ and then discuss what happens when $x\in(-\infty,-3)$ or when $x\in(-3,0)$ or $x\in(0,\infty)$. What you did was multiply by $x$ but if $x$ is negative you need to flip the sign of the inequality so it's better to avoid multiplying inequalities.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Because it's tge absolute value?

Comment: Yes, $|A|\leq B$ is equivalent to $-B\leq A\leq B$, both inequalities simultaneously (an **and**).

Answer (score 1):

We can write $$|x-3|\le 2|x|,$$ three cases arise and this equation is to be re-written each time.

1- $-\infty< x \le 0,$ then $$-(x-3)\le -2x \implies x \le -3 \implies x \in (-\infty, -3].$$

2- $ 0 <x \le 3,$ then $$-(x-3) \le 2x \implies -3x \le -3 \implies x\ge 1 \implies x \in [1,3].$$

3- $3<x <\infty,$ then $$(x-3) \le 2x \implies -x \le 3 \implies x \ge -3 \implies x \in [3,\infty).$$

So the net solution is $$x \in (-\infty,-3] \cup [1,\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

A clean procedure is to set

$$|1-\frac{3}{x}|=2$$

for the two break points at $x=-3$ and $x=1$. For each of the resulting intervals, just pick any point within to check the validity of the inequality.

$$x<-3,\>\>\>  |1-\frac{3}{-5}|\le 2, \>\>\>true$$
$$-3<x<1,\>\>\>  |1-\frac{3}{-1}|\le 2, \>\>\>false$$
$$x>1,\>\>\>  |1-\frac{3}{2}|\le 2, \>\>\>true$$

Thus, the solutions are

$$x\le -3\>\>\>\text{and}\>\>\>x\ge 1$$